# How to iterate last 5 value from array list

Tags: java, list, url, arraylist

Hi i am trying to access a string using array list where i am using  following code for this

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String args[])
{
      URL url;
              ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
              ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
              List commodity=null;
              List pric=null;
              int c,p=0;
         try {
            // get URL content
              String a="http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=Paddy";
              url = new URL(a);
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
              StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
              String inputLine;
              while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
          //    System.out.println(inputLine);
              String s=inputLine.replace("|", "\n");
              s=s.replace("~"," ");
              StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                    while(str.hasMoreTokens())
            {
              String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();
              String price = str.nextElement().toString();
              list1.add(mandi);
              list2.add(price);
         }

       }
               {
                   commodity = list1.subList(200, 207);
                   pric = list2.subList(0, 8);
                   for (c = 0, p = 0; c < commodity.size() && p < pric.size(); c++, p++) {
System.out.println(commodity.get(c));
                   }
               }}
         catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
         }
}
}
```

Here i am getting following Excepton `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 207`

if i use

```
{


  commodity = list1.subList(200, 206);

  for (c = 0, p = 0; c < commodity.size() && p < pric.size(); c++, p++) {
      System.out.println(commodity.get(c));
     }
      }}
```

it work fine i know why it is happening  but i want to handle this  because i  in future string could be till 207, 208

How can i get my output

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. You do not need `subList` just to iterate over the last 5 elements. Also, the selected answer is wrong and will not deal with lists that will contain fewer than the desired amount of elements. For instance, if your list only contains 4 elements, I believe you would like to iterate these even if there are less than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `commodity = list1.subList(200, 207);` doesn't work but `commodity = list1.subList(200, 206);` works, this means index is out of bounds and 206 is the last item in the ArrayList. So I am assuming you want sub-string from 200 to length-1. So you can use:

```
commodity = list1.subList(200, lis1.size()-1);
```

Now, hard coding the start index 200 is also dangerous, the list size might be lesser than 200! So you can use something like:

```
if(list1.size>5)
    commodity = list1.subList(lis1.size()-5, lis1.size()-1);
else
    //it is an error condition , so handle it as you want to
```

You could also perform a check to see if size is greater than 200, if you're sure thats where the list1 should start.
Another approach could be iterate through element and add them individually. This should be done if you have a way of identifying whether it is mandi or price.
PS: There is no harm in having a check even if you're sure that the length of list is more than 200. It is a good practice. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user3598351 Why did you select this answer? The logic doesn't make any sense. Why would you need at least 6 elements in the array to iterate over the last 5?

Comment: @plalx Well I gave it as 6 just as an example to tell that you can use size()-numberOfElements you want to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last 5 values, why don't you do it like

```
final int listSize = list1.size();

if (listSize >= 5) {
    commodity = list1.subList(listSize - 5, listSize - 1);

    // ...
} else {
    // Error handling
}
```

?

Comment: my prob is this is 5 element are not in list then exception can come  so how will handle that

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
  commodity = list1.subList(list.size()-5, list1.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `subList` to iterate over the last five elements, unless you want to keep a reference to these.

```
int i = yourList.size() - 5;

for (i = i < 0? 0 : i; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
    //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just get the last five elements and handle the exceptions:

```
    try {
        commodity = list1.subList(list1.size()-5, list1.size());
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        /* when list1 has less than 5 elements */
        commodity = list1;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        /* when list1 is null */
        commodity = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    System.out.println(commodity);
```